# How do i reprompt invalid user input and restore the value?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain why the while loop ask whatNight twice? and how to reprompt invalid user input if user input something other than 'r' or 'c'

```
    for(int x = 1; x <= inputInt; x++) {
    char whatNight  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter c or r for what type of night").charAt(0); 
    boolean pleasework = whatNight == 'c' || whatNight == 'C';
    boolean imbeggingu = whatNight == 'r' || whatNight == 'R';
    boolean doesNotWork = whatNight != 'c' && whatNight != 'C' && whatNight != 'r' && whatNight != 'R';

    //why does the while loop ask twice even if u enter c or r?
    while(pleasework || imbeggingu || doesNotWork) {

        if(doesNotWork) 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INvalid letter");
             whatNight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter c or r for what type of night").charAt(0);
        //reprompt not storing in whatNight variable :/

             if(pleasework)  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered c for carnight");

             else if(imbeggingu)  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered r for regular night");
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I would recommend you to debug your values as a first step e.g

```
System.out.println(pleasework);
```

Your concepts logic is pretty off aswell and you should rethink how you want to handle the issue. For example when your input is not C or R you ask for a new input but you dont set any boolean according to it.

this should work!

```
for(int x = 1; x <= inputInt; x++) {
    char whatNight  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter c or r for what type of night").charAt(0); 
    whatNight = checkInput(whatNight);
    boolean nightC = whatNight == 'c' || whatNight == 'C';
    boolean nightR = whatNight == 'r' || whatNight == 'R';

    if(nightC) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered c for carnight");
    } else if(nightR) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered r for regular night");
    }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------

private char checkInput(char input) {
    if(input == 'c' || input == 'C' || input == 'r' || input == 'R') {
        return input;
    }
    char whatNight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You entered a wrong letter, enter either c or r for what type of night it was").charAt(0);
    return checkInput(whatNight);
}
```

If you dont understand something let me know and I'll explain!